# How to fix jest with mongodb on gitlab issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, jestjs, gitlab

jest-mongodb (npm run test) work well on local but not work on gitlab-ci, it was working suddenly it stopped working and show the following error.

file: jest.config.js

```
const merge = require('merge');
const ts_preset = require('ts-jest/jest-preset');
const jest_mongodb = require('@shelf/jest-mongodb/jest-preset');

module.exports = merge.recursive(ts_preset, jest_mongodb, {
  globals: {
    test_url: `http://${process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1'}:${
      process.env.PORT || 3000
    }`,
  },
  preset: '@shelf/jest-mongodb',
  setupFiles: ['dotenv/config'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/__tests__/helpers'],
});
```

Log:

```
Error: Jest: Got error running 
globalSetup - /builds/elo/elo-api/node_modules/@shelf/jest-mongodb/setup.js, 
reason: Instance Exited before 
being ready and without throwing an error!
```

[image]
Please can you help me ?